# How do i sort after .map?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to sort the below list by numberOfPlayer, but i'm not sure how quite to get it done after .map. Would I need to do a .sort prior to the map? if yes, how would i do it using the below? I am wanting to sort by numberOfPlayer, game.Game.numberOfPlayer

```
function Popularity(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchGames()
    }, [])

    // sort by # of active players
    let f2p = props.gameRatings.map(game => {
        let altText = `${game.Game.title} logo`
        return (
            <li key={game.id} className="rating-item">
                <div className="rating-item_game">
                    <img src={game.Game.logo} alt={altText} className="rating-item_game_logo" />
                </div>
                <div className="rating-item_rating">
                    <h3>{game.Game.title}</h3>
                    <p>Active Players: {game.Game.numberOfPlayer}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {f2p}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        gameRatings: state.gameR.gameRatings
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchGames: () => dispatch(gameActions.fetchGames())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Popularity);
```

Comment: Oops sorry I want to sort by numberOfPlayer, by the total number of players being called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an [`#Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) before mapping.

Sort callback should return a positive/negative/neutral number depending on the type of sort you want (see docs).

```
arrayCopy.gameRatings
  .sort((gameA, gameB) => gameA.Game.numberOfPlayer - gameB.Game.numberOfPlayer)
  .map(game => {...});
```

Comment: Be careful, `sort` mutates the array in place, which is an anti-pattern in React and it's prone to create bugs. `[...props.gameRatings].sort(/*...*/)` would remove this risk.

Comment: You should really sort in the [selector](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) since sorted data is derived data and having the logic woven in your jsx generation makes it non reusable.